# Is it possible to install specific package versions used by the installer, before the installer runs?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, curtin

The current version of Curtin on the 20.04 live installer fails to properly detect my disks, and I thus cannot install Ubuntu 20.04. A newer version of Curtin has fixed this issue (19.3-68-g6cbdc02d-0ubuntu1).

Is there a way for me to upgrade Curtin?